# How do I adapt my flipclock code to function on multiple instances?

Tags: javascript, countdown, clock, multiple-instances, flipclock

I cannot get the flip clock to work on multiple instances. I try to attribute different ID's but it does not matter.

```
<div class="captainmarvel2" style="width: 30%">
 <img src="Pictures/captainlogo.png">
 <h5>In Theaters 8 March 2019</h5>
 <div class="clock" id ="clock4"></div>
 <a href="https://www.myvue.com/film/captain-marvel" target="_blank" id="myButton3Hide" disabled>Buy Ticket on Vue</a>
</div>

<div class="endgame2" style="width: 30%">
 <img src="Pictures/endgame.png">
 <h5>In Theaters 8 March 2019</h5>
 <div class="clock" id ="clock5"></div>
 <a href="https://www.myvue.com/film/avengers-endgame" target="_blank" id="myButton5Hide" disabled>Buy Ticket on Vue</a>
</div>
```

```
/* Countdown until Captain Marvel Release */

var next_show = new Date('2019-04-11T21:46:00');
var diff = next_show.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

var showtime = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
var clock = $('#clock4').FlipClock({
  clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  countdown: true
});

setTimeout(function(){ 
  checktime();
}, 1000);

function checktime(){
  t = clock.getTime();
  if(t<=0){
    $('#myButton4hide').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#clock4').remove();
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    checktime();
  }, 1000);
}
clock.setTime(showtime);
clock.start();

/* Countdown until Endgame Release */

var next_show = new Date('2019-05-10T22:24:00');
var diff = next_show.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

var showtime = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
var clock = $('#clock5').FlipClock({
  clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  countdown: true
});

setTimeout(function(){ 
  checktime();
}, 1000);

function checktime(){
  t = clock.getTime();
  if(t<=0){
    $('#myButton5hide').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#clock5').remove();
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    checktime();
  }, 1000);
}
clock.setTime(showtime);
clock.start();
```

So, I want to have three clocks like this next to each other. Above I have included two of the clocks I have been trying this with because I haven't tried with the third yet before I get two working.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you tried to use three instances?

Comment: Btw, `t` is an undeclared global variable.

Comment: Hi Bergi,
I added the two flip clock codes I have been working with above. I haven't dared to try with the third one yet before I get two working.

Comment: Yes, you cannot just duplicate the code when it is using global variables. You will need to put them in a local scope - e.g. with an IIFE or blocks and `let`. Or even better simple put the code in a function (thereby making the variables local), and *call* it twice with different arguments.

Comment: So what I initially tried to do was to rename the variables to clock1, clock2, so forth, although this did not work either, possibly because I am using a plugin? 

I am not familiar with IIFE, blocks or let. I have been learning web applications for a few weeks and a real beginner.

Comment: Renaming all the variables, all the functions, and that undeclared `t` variable, should actually work. You may try it again. Of course the `FlipClock` plugin itself might also have a bug that prevents multiple instances, but I doubt it. And yes, try to learn about those things I told you :-)